# How to lower the mobile LCP score in Google Pagespeed Insights?

Tags: optimization, mobile-website, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to fix our mobile LCP score on PageSpeed Insights.

I've been banging my head over the past 2 weeks on this.

Our site is using Wordpress and it's cached with Cloudflare Enterprise. Also, we are using
FlyPress for the optimization (CSS and Java).

Our LCP is 3.7 at last check and we need to get it down to at least 2.5 .. It was 5 when I started
and so many other metrics were way offer. I've been able to get things down to a reasonable level.

Can someone take a look at the homepage, https://www.newbonuses.com

I'd really appreciate any advice on what needs to be done and how..

Tried different settings, disabling and enabling plugins, delaying individual javascripts, etc.. I've tried just about every combination, which ended up helping alot with the other metrics.

The "Render Delay" is very high in the LCP.

Answer (score 1):

Your CrUX mobile LCP is now 2.7. This metric is aggregated over 28 days, so it will take that long to reflect your improvements.

If it has already gone down from 3.7, I'd expect it to get under 2.5 quite soon.

TTFB is quite high, indicating your typical mobile users are probably on a slow network. So you have an uphill battle to improve their LCP.

Don't preload images that are not initially visible. And preload the main image first.

For some reason your main image is loading with a low priority (Chrome). Try adding fetchpriority="high" to the preload. Also imagesrcset='' imagesizes='' is strange and may be confusing the preload handler.

And 100k for a small image like that is big. Try converting it to something like a png and compressing it.

Comment: +1 to the good advice here (especially `fetchpriority="high"` if you're going to stick with the preload, but you should consider dropping it since the image is finable statically in the page). 1.7s TTFB is where you should put your efforts next as it means there's little margin for any other part of the path to a <2.5s LCP. This [Optimize TTFB article](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-ttfb) might give you some starting points.